# Why throwing an error : specified cast is not valid?

Tags: c#, sql

I used 'userid' in sql is int datatype and in backend(.cs) also used same int data type then why throwing this error:'specified cast is not valid'

```
var userRowsCustId = dsCustReg.Tables[0]
                              .AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(r => r.Field<int>("AccountNo"));

var allRowsCustId = dsAllTables.Tables[0]
                               .AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(r => r.Field<int>("UserId"));

IEnumerable<int> allIntersectingCustIds = userRowsCustId.Except(allRowsCustId);

if (allIntersectingCustIds.Any())
{
}
```

what is the solution for this error?

error throwing at `r => r.Field<int>("AccountNo")`

Comment: Have you used a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill the table or how have you filled the `DataTable`? Is `AccountNo` also an `int`-column? Look at the `dsCustReg.Columns` in the debugger.

Comment: What data type are `AccountNo` and `UserId` in the database?

Comment: Also, your code seems to have a naming or logical issue. Intersecting usually means that they share the same values but `Except` returns all user-rows which don't exist in the cust-rows. Maybe you want to use `Intersect`.

Comment: Maybe your field is `int?` (nullable int)

Comment: userid and account no are same from frent end i am showing accno and in backend use user id

Comment: account no use in excel sheet col and userid is int col in sql

Comment: Yes i used data adapter for fill data into dataset

Comment: are you sure that your `AccountNo` field is of datatype `int` in your database ?

Comment: Is the Account No. field nullable? if it is that is probably what is tripping up the conversion (assuming that the Account No. is an int datatype.

Comment: I got it..its accepting when I replaced into with double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it..its accepting when I replaced into with double